# New field add in array zero postion object in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to add value in  $row['data'] if it is empty

```
$row['data'] = $this->Employee_model->GetEmployeeRecord($id);
    if(empty($row['data'])){

    }
```

Comment: so, what is the issue?

Comment: You mean something like `$row['data'] = "SOMEVALUE";` ?

Comment: What u need to ad and what is the issue

Comment: If `$row['data']` is an array use `array_push` else use `$row['data'] = 'Hello World';`

Answer (score 1):

the functions will only works if the value doens't contain any value. otherwise it will not array push the new value to it. i've made a little code for it as example, but should work with your code aswell, just change the set value back to

> $this->Employee_model->GetEmployeeRecord($id)"

and it should work again

here is the example code:

```
<?php
$id = 1;
function GetEmployeeRecord($id) {
    return $id;
}
$row['data'] = $this->GetEmployeeRecord($id);

if(empty($row['data'])){
    array_push($row['data'], "test");
    echo "if data is empty: <br>";
} else {
    echo "data is not empty <br>";
}
print_r($row['data']);

?>
```

Comment: one status field add like status->0;